# json instant search

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, search

I am trying to make an instant search functionality within json. The code seems right but definitely doesn't work. Would you please guys have a look and help me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/hMyr7/

Comment: We're gonna need more than, "here's my code, fix it".  What's wrong with it?  What's not working?

Comment: why are you using `async: false`? AJAX is _supposed_ to be asynchronous

Comment: For a start, your jsFiddle includes MooTools instead of jQuery. Fix'd: http://jsfiddle.net/hMyr7/7/

Comment: `response` is an array, you must treat it like one. `response[0].etc...`

Comment: Additionally, `async: false` doesn't do anything for a jsonp request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSONP represents the data that your AJAX call recieves. [It](http://mykolaiv.cityfacts.pro/?s=city&feed=json&callback=jsonCallback) looks like this:

```
jsonCallback([{
    "id": 41,
    "title": "My city",
    "permalink": "http:\/\/mykolaiv.cityfacts.pro\/my-city\/",
    "content": "",
    "meta": {
        "ultimatum_layout": [""],
        "_edit_last": ["1"],
        "_edit_lock": ["1346784971:1"]
    },
    "excerpt": "",
    "date": "2012-09-04 18:26:50",
    "author": "oyeremchuk",
    "categories": [],
    "tags": [null]
}]);
```

The outermost node is an array. To access the first element in that array you can use an indexer: `response[0]`. The question then is "What do you want from your data?"

Judging from your js, you probably want to loop over the whole response, and pull `id`, `title` and `permalink` from each item. This ought to do for your callback:

```
    success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            var data_id = item.id;
            var data_title = item.title;
            var data_viewCount = item.permalink;

            var final = "<div id='id'><div>" + data_id + "</div><div id='title'>" + data_title + "</div></div>";

            $("#results").append(final);

        });
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hMyr7/15/.

Comment: Thanks a lot RichardTowers. I just want to search data within json and display the results instantly.

Comment: RichardTowers when I am typing city I have got a few instant results but only one of them correct which has got "city" word...Is there anything you can help me with. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You should probably sort it out on the server side. For example `ci` returns [multiple results](http://mykolaiv.cityfacts.pro/?s=ci&feed=json&callback=jsonCallback). You [could hack it on the client side](http://jsfiddle.net/hMyr7/16/) though.

Answer (score 3):

I had to enable jQuery on your jsfiddle...

Once I did so, it seems that the server is returning a 500 server error for the ajax request.

You'll need to investigate the server side response as there is nothing we can do to troubleshoot this for you.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you....here is the link

http://mykolaiv.cityfacts.pro/info/?feed=json&callback=jsonCallback

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your JavaScript console?

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined"` -- because there is no `data` or `data.items` in your JSON.

Try changing

```
if (response.data.items) {
```

to

```
if (response.data && response.data.items) {
```

and it will at least fail gracefully.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/hMyr7/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot Blazemonger. Please have a look at my json. http://mykolaiv.cityfacts.pro/?s=city&feed=json&callback=jsonCallback

Would you be able to help me please?

Comment: Hi Kevin, this is the link sorry for the wrong one http://mykolaiv.cityfacts.pro/?s=city&feed=json&callback=jsonCallback

Comment: There's just no 'data' in there, with or without 'data.items'. That needs to be fixed server-side.